# Can't boot the CentOS 7 that is installed on my USB on other computers

Tags: centos, boot, usb, uefi, bios

I just install a CentOS 7 by DVD iso on my USB as what you'll do to install normal centos (not live-USB) with my laptop with UEFI boot mode and it can be successfully booted on my laptop too.

So as I installed it from UEFI mode it should be able to boot in any computer that is in UEFI mode (in theory) but I can't boot it on other computers. I've entered BIOS and `disable secure boot` `enable CSM` but it kept returning the following error:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

And I don't know how to solve this

And here's the image for configuration in BIOS and also the log it returned when I boot from my USB:

[image: image for config in BIOS and err log]

Comment: Is there no option to boot in legacy mode only?

Comment: @RamanSailopal For the first image yes there is `legacy only` but I'm sure that the CentOS 7 is installed under UEFI mode which should be only able to boot under UEFI (right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue today while trying to install CentOS on a USB drive. It was resolved by copying the "missing" file from one folder to another on the ESI partition.

I booted into an existing Ubuntu partition... you could do the same with a rescue disk. I ran `sudo blkid` to get the list of partitions... for me, the EFI partition on the USB drive was /dev/sdc1 . So I mounted it, and copied the file:

```
mkdir /tmp/sdefi
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /tmp/sdefi
sudo cp /tmp/sdefi/EFI/centos/grubx64.efi /tmp/sdefi/EFI/BOOT/
sudo umount /tmp/sdefi
```

After that I was able to boot from USB. If you try it, be sure to substitute the right partition name for /dev/sdc1 in the mount command.